# How to store the saved image in a folder using cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am capturing image with cordova using reference:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

It's working fine. But when i click on save, the image is not saved/ stored in my phone.

Is there any extra js required apart from the code?
Or please tell me if there is any method to store image in a particular folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following. It will save the image in the sample folder and also randomfilename should be you file name of taken image(generate new name every time using randomNumber generation or use the default camera returned file name).

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
var directory = "sampleApp/";
var randomFileName = "sampleimg.png"; // this should be the filename 
saveImage(imageData,randomFileName,directory);
    }, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });

function saveImage(imageData,fileName,directory){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function gotFile(fileSystem) {
           fileSystem.root.getDirectory(directory, {create: true},  function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
               fileSystem.getFile("dummy.txt",{create: true,exclusive:false},function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
                    var path = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.txt","");
                    fileEntry.remove();
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileTransfer.download(imageData, path+""+fileName,function(theFile){

                        alert("File Downloaded Successfully");
                    },function(error){
                        alert("File Download Failed"+ error.code);
                    });
                },fail);
           });
    }, fail);
}

function fail(e){
    alert("Error Occured"+ e.code); 
}
```